# Dynamically change the color of listbox items in code behind(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a traffic application. The light status is updated in the listbox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxCallProgress"  ItemsSource="{Binding Messages,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="373" FontSize="8" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

For the Messages:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
```

To update messages to the listbox.

```
    void UpdateMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.Messages.Add(message); }));
            });
        }
```

Now if the string `message` contains the keyword "green", then I want to set the item color on the listbox as color green, etc.

How?

Comment: Foreground="{Binding}"

Comment: Are the strings mutable? Or will they stay the same for the entire life-cycle?

Comment: @Herdo, Yes, the strings are mutable.

Comment: Why do you use a delegate to add to the Messages?

Comment: @Blam, I don't know. I borrowed the piece of code from somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

with the power of WPF binding you can use the value to bind to the desired property `Background` and the implicit converter will do the rest for you.

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

you can choose to bind `Foreground` in case if you want to change the text color

---

**Using converters**

if simple binding is not sufficient enough you may use converters to perform custom logic of conversion, eg converting `The light is red` to `Brushes.Red`

```
public class MyColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = value as string;

        if(text.Contains("red"))
           return Brushes.Red;

        return Brushes.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

usage

```
<DataTemplate xmlns:l="your namespace to converter class">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <l:MyColorConverter x:Key="MyColorConverter" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyColorConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: There's an implicit converter to automatically convert "random(lower/upper)"-case color names (as plain string) into the `System.Windows.Media.Brush`?

Comment: Hi, I need more code. The color can be yellow, green and red. For example, if `message` is "The light is red", then how to binding it to red color? If the `message` is "after 10 seconds, the color will be green", then how?

Comment: @Love, in that case a converter can help you. you may need to define the pattern like where to find the color. for example `how to identify` the color `red` from the sentence `the light is red`

Comment: @pushpraj, I want something like `if message.Contains("red")`, then change the color.

Comment: @Herdo the implicit converter is able to convert from upper or lower case color names as long as they are from the list of color names. you may refer the list from [Colors Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Love, could you also tell me that is there a defined list of colors? or need to verify all the colors from [Colors Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @pushpraj, just three colors-- Red, green and yellow. It is a test project, I just want it work first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61420/discussion-between-love-and-pushpraj).

Comment: @Love, my apologies for not being able to assist you in your last query. my internet connection broke down suddenly. Seems like you've already figured it out. namespace is usually prefixed by `clr-namespace` if you are referring from project or assemblies, eg `xmlns:l="clr-namespace:IVRLoadTester"`